# Render extjs components into a grid column once renderer has run

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs, extjs4, render

I have a [grid column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column) with a custom renderer. Like so.

```
grid.healthCheckColumn = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
    id: 'healthCheckColumn',
    header: 'Health Check',
    renderer: Ext.bind(me.renderHealthCheckColumn, me)
});
```

This renderer returns a div with class 'health-check-button', and that renders fine. Here’s my problem.

Once the renderer has populated a grid cell with the div, I want an event to fire which will allow me to render an ExtJS component to that div. Here’s the component I want to render:

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    ui: 'plain',
    disable: val,
    text: 'Analyze',
    renderTo: div_element
});
```

The reason this won’t work is because an ExtJS component can only render to an element that’s already in the DOM, and that element won’t exist until *after* the renderer has run.

Obviously, I could put a call to Ext.defer() in my renderer, to fire an event after a timeout, but that seems hackish. That solution (to a similar question) was suggested here:

[Ext js event fired or called after renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539177/ext-js-event-fired-or-called-after-renderer)

I’ve tried to figure out the order in which events fire, and in what sequence, but that’s not documented and I can’t make sense of the ExtJS source code. `beforerender`, `render`, and `afterrender` all fire *before* the renderer runs, which isn’t helpful.

Any suggestions? I’m running ExtJS 4.3.

Comment: Suggestion is to do it the "hackish" way, for the reasons named in the article you linked (a single cell has no events fired at all, for it is no component on its own).